# Extjs DataView store.reload re-adds items

Tags: extjs

I have an extjs dataview:

```
    var dv = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
        store: this.eventInstanceImagesStore,
        tpl: [
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{name:stripTags}">',
            '<div class="thumb"><img src="http://stimages.blob.core.windows.net/medium/{value}" title="{name:htmlEncode}"></div>',
            '<span class="x-editable">{shortName:htmlEncode}</span>',
            '</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
        ],
        multiSelect: true,
        trackOver: true,
        overItemCls: 'x-item-over',
        itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
        emptyText: 'No images to display',
        plugins: [
           // Ext.create('Ext.ux.DataView.DragSelector', {}),
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.DataView.LabelEditor', { dataIndex: 'name' })
        ],
        prepareData: function (data) {
            Ext.apply(data, {
                shortName: Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(data.name, 15),
                sizeString: Ext.util.Format.fileSize(data.size),
                dateString: Ext.util.Format.date(data.lastmod, "m/d/Y g:i a")
            });
            return data;
        }
    });
```

I also have a file upload form which, when the image has been successfully uploaded I am reloading the dataview:

```
 dv.store.reload({
      params: {
          id: eid
      }
 });
```

However, when the reload happens it seems to re-add the images twice. So I end up with 2 dataviews... Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing your store implementation.  It could be something like having your store autoload set to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `dv.store.removeAll();` first before doing a

```
dv.store.reload({
      params: {
          id: eid
      }
 });
```